# How to set the palette Colors from perl script?

Tags: terminal, xterm

I have a perl script which randomly selects a FG and BG colors for my terminal.
I use the following print commands to set the FG and BG on the fly:

```
   print "\033]10;<fg_color>\007";
   print "\033]11;<bg_color>\007";
```

I need to set the palette colors too, but i'm having problems finding an example on how to do it.
Can any one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your terminal implements xterm's [OSC 10](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Operating-System-Commands:OSC-Ps;Pt-ST:Ps-=-1-0.1015) and [OSC 11](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Operating-System-Commands:OSC-Ps;Pt-ST:Ps-=-1-1.1016) as indicated in the question, then it probably also implements [OSC 4](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Operating-System-Commands:OSC-Ps;Pt-ST:Ps-=-4;c;spec.123F):

> *Ps* = 4 ; *c* ; ***spec*** ⇒  Change Color Number *c* to the color
> specified by ***spec***.

For example

```
print "\033]4;1;green\007";
print "\033]4;1;green\033\\";
```

using green to replace color 1 (red) where xterm also would accept an [RGB setting:](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/blob/f2f7de6391685780e5024438c666d032f2508f5f/misc.c#L2988)

```
/*
 * Set or query entries in the Acolors[] array by parsing pairs of color/name
 * values from the given buffer.
 *
 * The color can be any legal index into Acolors[], which consists of the
 * 16/88/256 "ANSI" colors, followed by special color values for the various
 * colorXX resources.  The indices for the special color values are not
 * simple to work with, so an alternative is to use the calls which pass in
 * 'first' set to the beginning of those indices.
 *
 * If the name is "?", report to the host the current value for the color.
 */
```

The legal values for spec are determined by [**`XParseColor`**](https://linux.die.net/man/3/xparsecolor) (in [xterm](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/blob/f2f7de6391685780e5024438c666d032f2508f5f/misc.c#L3132) -- for other terminals, that is implementation-dependent and generally undocumented, making that aspect off-topic).

Comment: Thank you very much, That is exactly what i needed :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think, that you can set the palette. You just can select from the palette. See [here](http://blogs.perl.org/users/ab5tract/2016/09/introducing-terminalprint.html) for examples.

The palette depends on your Terminal. For [XTerm](https://unix4lyfe.org/xterm/) the palette is set in `~/.Xresources`. This is my current configuration:

```
XTerm*color0:     rgb:00/00/00
XTerm*color1:     rgb:80/00/00
XTerm*color2:     rgb:00/80/00
XTerm*color3:     rgb:80/80/00
XTerm*color4:     rgb:00/00/80
XTerm*color5:     rgb:80/00/80
XTerm*color6:     rgb:00/80/80
XTerm*color7:     rgb:c0/c0/c0
XTerm*color8:     rgb:80/80/80
XTerm*color9:     rgb:aa/00/00
XTerm*color10:    rgb:00/aa/00
XTerm*color11:    rgb:aa/aa/00
XTerm*color12:    rgb:00/00/aa
XTerm*color13:    rgb:aa/00/aa
XTerm*color14:    rgb:00/aa/aa
XTerm*color15:    rgb:ff/ff/ff
```